# Accessing CloudWatch Event Variables in CodePipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline

In my project I'm using Lambda functions in order to trigger other CodePipelines (SubPipeline1, SubPipeline2, ...) when necessary (based on this approach described [here in a blogpost](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/devops/adding-custom-logic-to-aws-codepipeline-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/)).
Other than this example the Lambda functions are actually part of a CodePipeline (OrchestratingPipeline) themselfes.

```
CodeCommitCloudWatchEvent -> OrchestratingPipeline
                             |                  |
                             v                  v
                      SelectiveTriggerFnct1 SelectiveTriggerFnct2
                             |                  |
                             v                  v
                        SubPipeline1        SubPipeline2
```

In these Lambda functions I now want to access the original CloudWatch Event which contains an attribute "OldCommitId". How can I get this done?

I already checked/tried:

- When starting the pipeline I can not pass any additional parameters to the pipeline
- The [CodeCommit source stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeCommit.html#action-reference-CodeCommit-variables) does not provide the OldCommitId but just the current one